# Android CTS: "Error during Sync: timeout"

Tags: android, android-cts

- UBUNTU : 12.04
- Android CTS : 6.0_r5
- ADB version : Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32 (Revision 09a0d98bebce-android)

When running a CTS test on my target board, I got "Error duing Sync: timeout" so any test is not executed. I tried to the same test with CTS 6.0_r3 but the result is same.

BTW, when my coworker run the same CTS with the same target board (that is my board) on his UBUNTU (12.04), the CTS tests are completed.

```
cts-tf > albertc@albertc-UBUNTU:~/android/android-cts$ ./tools/cts-tradefed 
Android CTS 6.0_r5 build:2736048
04-21 12:30:26 I/DeviceManager: Detected new device 16419d187100000006fe82c0
cts-tf > run cts -c android.hardware.camera2.cts.StaticMetadataTest --skip-media-download --skip-preconditions
04-21 12:30:41 I/TestInvocation: Starting invocation for 'cts' on build '2736048' on device 16419d187100000006fe82c0
04-21 12:30:41 I/16419d187100000006fe82c0: Created result dir 2016.04.21_12.30.41
04-21 12:30:41 I/CtsTest: ABIs: [armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a]
04-21 12:30:46 I/16419d187100000006fe82c0: Collecting device info
04-21 12:31:18 E/Device: Error during Sync: timeout.
04-21 12:31:58 I/16419d187100000006fe82c0: -----------------------------------------
04-21 12:31:58 I/16419d187100000006fe82c0: Test package arm64-v8a android.camera started
04-21 12:31:58 I/16419d187100000006fe82c0: -----------------------------------------
04-21 12:31:58 I/16419d187100000006fe82c0: arm64-v8a android.camera package complete: Passed 0, Failed 0, Not Executed 5
04-21 12:31:58 I/16419d187100000006fe82c0: -----------------------------------------
04-21 12:31:58 I/16419d187100000006fe82c0: Test package armeabi-v7a android.camera started
04-21 12:31:58 I/16419d187100000006fe82c0: -----------------------------------------
04-21 12:31:58 I/16419d187100000006fe82c0: Saved log device_logcat_7656355222403074253.zip
04-21 12:31:58 I/16419d187100000006fe82c0: Saved log host_log_3771779795412712371.zip
04-21 12:31:58 I/16419d187100000006fe82c0: armeabi-v7a android.camera package complete: Passed 0, Failed 0, Not Executed 5
04-21 12:31:58 I/16419d187100000006fe82c0: Created xml report file at file:///home/albertc/WorkSpace/android/android-cts/./tools/../../android-cts/repository/results/2016.04.21_12.30.41/testResult.xml
04-21 12:31:58 I/16419d187100000006fe82c0: XML test result file generated at 2016.04.21_12.30.41. Passed 0, Failed 0, Not Executed 10
04-21 12:31:58 I/16419d187100000006fe82c0: Time: 1m 17s
```

Comment: I got another kind of error, and then CTS stop..
[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37849303/android-cts-execution-stopped-abnormally-on-half-way)

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer by myself. It looks like this problem happens when updating sdk tools through Android studio.

Here is my step to fix this problem.
Let's assume you install Android SDK in `$HOME/android/android_studio` and installed SDK tools `$HOME/android/android-sdk-linux`.

1. Remove Android SDK tools.
2. Download SDK tool only from https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other (Direct link: http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz)
3. Extract SDK tool to `$HOME/android/android-sdk-linux` again.
4. Reboot your Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply reinstall or update the SDK tool, called AndrSDK Build-Tools  and AndrSDK Platform-Tools.