# android cts execution stopped abnormally on half-way

Tags: java, android, cts

Android CTS execution stopped abnormally half-way. Does anyone know how to fix it?

**Version:**
Android OS 6.0.1(64 bits) + Android CTS 6.0_r6

**Command:**

```
run cts --plan CTS --shards 3 --skip-preconditions
```

Error Logs:

```
06-16 03:05:20 I/82abb56f: dEQP-EGL.functional.native_coord_mapping.native_pixmap#rgba5551_depth_stencil_render PASS 
06-16 03:05:20 I/82abb56f: dEQP-EGL.functional.native_coord_mapping.native_pixmap#rgba8888_no_depth_no_stencil_clear PASS 
06-16 03:05:20 I/82abb56f: dEQP-EGL.functional.native_coord_mapping.native_pixmap#rgba8888_no_depth_no_stencil_render PASS 
06-16 03:05:20 I/82abb56f: dEQP-EGL.functional.native_coord_mapping.native_pixmap#rgba8888_no_depth_stencil_clear PASS 
06-16 03:05:20 I/82abb56f: dEQP-EGL.functional.native_coord_mapping.native_pixmap#rgba8888_no_depth_stencil_render PASS 
06-16 03:05:20 I/82abb56f: dEQP-EGL.functional.native_coord_mapping.native_pixmap#rgba8888_depth_no_stencil_clear PASS 
06-16 03:05:20 I/82abb56f: dEQP-EGL.functional.native_coord_mapping.native_pixmap#rgba8888_depth_no_stencil_render PASS 
06-16 03:05:20 I/82abb56f: dEQP-EGL.functional.native_coord_mapping.native_pixmap#rgba8888_depth_stencil_clear PASS 
06-16 03:05:20 I/82abb56f: dEQP-EGL.functional.native_coord_mapping.native_pixmap#rgba8888_depth_stencil_render PASS 
06-16 03:05:20 I/82abb56f: dEQP-EGL.functional.native_coord_mapping.native_pixmap#other_clear PASS 
06-16 03:05:20 I/82abb56f: dEQP-EGL.functional.native_coord_mapping.native_pixmap#other_render PASS 
06-16 03:05:21 E/CtsTest: search postcondition failed
java.lang.AssertionError: search postcondition failed
    at com.android.cts.tradefed.testtype.DeqpTestRunner.selectRunBatch(DeqpTestRunner.java:1247)
    at com.android.cts.tradefed.testtype.DeqpTestRunner.selectRunBatch(DeqpTestRunner.java:1200)
    at com.android.cts.tradefed.testtype.DeqpTestRunner.runTests(DeqpTestRunner.java:1318)
    at com.android.cts.tradefed.testtype.DeqpTestRunner.run(DeqpTestRunner.java:1893)
    at com.android.cts.tradefed.testtype.CtsTest.run(CtsTest.java:581)
    at com.android.tradefed.invoker.TestInvocation.runTests(TestInvocation.java:734)
    at com.android.tradefed.invoker.TestInvocation.prepareAndRun(TestInvocation.java:549)
    at com.android.tradefed.invoker.TestInvocation.performInvocation(TestInvocation.java:452)
    at com.android.tradefed.invoker.TestInvocation.invoke(TestInvocation.java:232)
    at com.android.tradefed.command.CommandScheduler$InvocationThread.run(CommandScheduler.java:449)
06-16 03:05:21 I/82abb56f: arm64-v8a com.drawelements.deqp.egl package complete: Passed 999, Failed 0, Not Executed 0
```

Comment: Does anybody meet the same error?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this with latest kernels, the problem has been identified by Google in tty driver, google bug (b/28979140). Basically the deqp test stops randomly here because of parsing issues of .qpa results based on which cts-tradefed decides to delete the configs that have already been run, these paring errors just mess up the cts-tradefed's deqp test state and cause this crash.
Fix from Google is in tty driver that fixes the parsing errors.